# Magento 1.7.0.2 List.phtml image hover

Tags: php, magento, attributes

My questions is how do I assign a custom attribute as an image for the hover image in the list.phtml file.

I have done my research and got the site to do what I want by using this code to call the image in the grid view on list.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
   title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
   class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135); ?>"
   width="135" height="135" 
   alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
   onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135) ?>';"
   onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(135) ?>';" />
</a>
```

This works if the hover image is assigned as the thumbnail.

My issue is that I am using [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-products-categories-multiple-images-and-custom-options.html) to import all of my products and it doesnt allow to assign a different image for base, small and thumbnail. You have to use the same image. ( Yes I can go in and select each image individually and select the thumbnail but this is not an options with the number of products I have)

Ok so what I have done is created a custom attribute for the products called hover image, added the column to the csv file and hey presto it works - the hover image gets assigend to the Hover Image option under Images as seen here:

[image]

So my question is how do i edit the line of code above so it calls the new 'hover_image' attribute instead of the thumbnail. I have tried changing thumbnail to 'hover_image' but the site crashes.

Help please, i feel so close but not quite there.

Comment: Did you check the log files for the reason of crash? Normally you're right by using `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')` if that's your attribute code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, here is the file: http://dansiop.com/169764586470.txt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your attribute "hover_image" is not loaded on you category page. to change that try this:

go to any module config xml file if you are not sure about which is best use you local.xml add these lines under the **config** node

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                    <hover_image/>
                </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Since "hover_image" has no yet a placeholder we need to add it. go to
`skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder`, here you can find placeholder for the normal images copy image.jpg and rename the copy to "hover_image.jpg"

After that, clear your cache. if you are using the product flat index, reindex it.
Then you should be able to use

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($_product, 'hover_image')
    ->resize(135) ?>
```

let me know if not

Comment: Hey thanks for your input - I don't have that option in my manage attributes - take a look at the options I have inside the attribute in questions: http://dansiop.com/attribute.png

Comment: ahh ok sorry its not under **Attribute Properties** it should be below under **Frontend Properties**

Comment: You've lost me now - where is that? If i go to my attribute I have no options for 'Frontend Properties' now as I have already made the attribute a 'Media Image'. The whole screen that I see is like this: http://dansiop.com/attribute2.png any ideas????

Comment: sorry you are right, i did not take this into account. however there is another option i will edit my answer

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your help but it's not working. I have tried in a config.xml file and a local.xml and it crashed my admin - just got it back - what file exactly do you suggest i put that code in?

Comment: if it is crashing your backend i think you have an error in your xml.
it does not really matter in which file you add this. however it must be under the `<config>` node like `<default>` or `<admin>`, i just tested it on my local machine and it works

Comment: i just saw that i wrote config.xml thats wrong i meant any config xml file :) just write it into your local.xml

Comment: OK it is a new install of magento and i have not edited any other xml files however I misunderstood your directions so no wonder it crashed as i put the comments outside the config so i have now placed it within the <config> in app > etc > local.xml and the front end crashes - here is the error file ( i have reindexed and cleared cache)  http://dansiop.com/717707639862.txt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38110/discussion-between-dan-davies-and-fantus)

Comment: okay that looks much better. now he is complaining about the image, because he cant find it under the path. normaly you have a path like "/a/t/at-t-8525-pda-1.jpg" which leads to `media/catalog/product/a/t/at-t-8525-pda-1.jpg` can you tell me the value of "hover_image" if its null that could case a problem

Comment: OK a bit of a development - i did another dig around and found this page: http://indieswebs.com/blog/magento-custom-image-attributes-handle-with-care/ so i did what it says and now the page doesn't crash but when i hover it shows the new placeholder i created! - is this any help for anyone to help me out?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? all of the products i have added have a 'hover_image' assigned to them

Comment: if the placeholer is show the image is not found. can you give us an example value of your "hover_image"

Comment: Not sure what you mean or how I can tell you the value of "hover_image"? As the original post shows, i upload the products and state the image i want to import. The image shows in the product 'image' tab as the original post image shows so it must import it correctly but doesnt want to display it - seems we are getting somewhere but not quite!

Comment: well yes some progress maybe :). you mentioned that you have a new installation, did you set the correct write permissions of the media and the var folder?. that can be a reason why the placeholder is displayed instead of the right image

Comment: Yes i have never had this issue before and also the other images are working - you can see the page in question here: http://www.geckodevelopment.co.uk/brittot/index.php/brittot-allstars.html?garment_type=6 The images are uploaded through media/import - i put them there and they get processed - could it be that the extension i use for importing. I have used it several times and when i want to add a new attribute it processes it fine - never tried with images before.

Comment: I have just checked and I can see the images have been moved from the import folder to here so it is working and the images are there but some reason the code is not reading or showing the images?? http://dansiop.com/images.png The hover image is there!!!

Comment: ok are you using the flat tables? if yes did your reindex you product data?

Comment: not sure what flat tables is but i have reindexed - i will try now agin - nope nothing Also I have nopticed that if you click on the product image to go in to the prpduct view the image assinged as the hover_image is there so i am really confused now

Comment: Worth adding that if i do not assign a image, small_image and thumbnail and only import the products with a hover_image, the hover_image becomes the main image so it is definately getting the image just not when i want to call it as hover_image!! so frustrating - anyone?